# Not able to view my earlier post!

Tags: support, questions, user-accounts, deleted-questions, profile-page

Are all posts that I have posted till date available? If so where to search? To search my previous posts, I clicked my name on the top of the page. But there one post (regarding learning perl - web materials) which I had posted nearly a month back wasn't there. It's too important for me as it contains useful links for learning perl. 
How to get that post please?

Comment: What specifically was this Q about? Perhaps it was migrated to another SE site or deleted?

Comment: Looked thru the last 30 days worth of deleted Q's and didn't see any about Perl. If you give me more info I can try and find out what happened.

Comment: Was it this Q? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18469686/how-to-split-files-using-perl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clicking on your name is the easiest way to access your stats page, from there you can click the "Questions" link towards the bottom to get the list of all the questions you've asked on a given SE site.

Comment: Oh!! Yes I checked this earlier but missed clicking `recent deleted posts`. I hope all my posts should be available always there so that there is no need to copy it on my system?

Answer (score 4):

The question is [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92768/perl-knowledge-book-or-materials). It was closed pretty fast as being opinion-based, and was categorized as abandoned by the system and [automatically deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/145982). Questions aren't really supposed to hang around closed; in theory they either get fixed and reopened, or eventually deleted.

There weren't any answers, and the only place the comments linked to was the Perl website, which doesn't seem like it would be hard to find on your own, but here are the links again:

- http://perldoc.perl.org/
- http://perldoc.perl.org/index-tutorials.html
- http://www.perl.org/books/library.html

Comment: Yes, that's the one! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Seriously I have an issue. I had been searching for good materials for understanding packages/namespaces in perl. But the docs/links aren't able to clarify this concept. It seems it assumes some knowledge of package/namespace already. But for me who is the 1st time learner of package, the docs fails to clear the fundamental from scratch. 1st I went through `modern perl` to understand package but it was not from basics and seemed to be a bit advanced. So, I went to `perl for begineers` book but here also the same issue. What sort of books are these that can't clear the fundamentals from scratch

Comment: @Ravi I have no idea, I don't know Perl, and this isn't really the place to try and explain it if I did. If you can come up with a specific question about Perl, feel free to post it; if you're just looking for a tutorial, Perl is pretty old, so I imagine that googling your issue will find tons of them

Comment: Just one thing I would like to add to my last comment above that the physical text books which I purchase and read are so nicely explained that once you read chapter 1 , the next chapter would be clear automatically and so on. It's too interesting to read physical books. But these online books mentioned aren't made that way. If you read a chapter, some terms would be such which had never appeared earlier. So, I have to search that term. Now, to understand this term, I need to understand other terms and finally I would find that I am only wandering, that's all! Also addressing @goldilocks

Comment: @Mat As Mat has assisted in the materials, I am addressing him also the above comments.