# My thread is missing!

Tags: support, specific-question

I had a thread mentioned below but its not present on the page that opens when I click my  name on the top. Its not in the 'deleted recent questions'.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90731/connect-nokia-n73-to-laptop-via-bluetooth?noredirect=1#comment136986_90731

I got the above link from my Q in the below thread which is present on the page that opens when I click on my name in the top of this page.

[No bluetooth adapters found: how to get rid of this error message?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92661/no-bluetooth-adapters-found-how-to-get-rid-of-this-error-message)

It was a matter of chance only that this thread had the link of what I was looking for.

I had to spend a lot of time to get this. I was expecting that all threads whatever I posted should be present and I can retrieve it whenever required. It its not so then I request to please do the needful so that a member can get all his threads whenever he needs.

Answer (score 2):

We went through this [last time](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1493/not-able-to-view-my-earlier-post). It's not in "deleted recent questions" because it was deleted months ago, because it was closed. Closed questions aren't meant to stick around forever, they were closed for a reason, so they get deleted automatically by the system if they have no answers. The only link in the comments was the Google search results for [linux bluetooth Nokia N73](https://www.google.com/search?q=linux+bluetooth+Nokia+N73), which doesn't exactly seem hard to come up with, but I guess that must be what you were looking for.